# Business trip to US on B1/B2 for two weeks

Tags: usa, canada, b1-b2-visas, chinese-citizens, canadian-residents

I am a Chinese citizen holding B1/B2 visa which will expire in 2022. I have entered US multiple time for leisure. I am a landed immigrant in Canada and hired by a Canadian accounting firm. My firm is engaged to perform an audit for a US company based in Florida. The partner wants to send me to US for this engagement. The work (ex. meeting with client, examine financial record...)will last around two weeks. 
Can I enter US with B1 to perform this work? 
Do I need to provide any other supporting material while going through US customs?

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Cindy Liu, working in the US, if found out, will likely make for many difficulties for travel in the future, not just in the US but in many more countries. Whether you will found out is hard to predict but it is not worth it.

Comment: @Willeke can u define working in US? B1 is a temporary business visitor visa and I am not sure if it covers my situation

Answer (score 1):

## B1 Visa Purpose

[You can use a B1 visa for the following purposes](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/business/business-visa-center/business-visa-center-faqs.html):

> ### What is business related (B-1) visitor visa travel?
>
> Generally, the travel appropriate for a business (B-1) visitor visa includes;
>
> - Consultation with business associates
> - Attend a scientific, educational, professional or business convention, or a conference on specific dates
> - Settle an estate
> - Negotiate a contract
> - Participate in short-term training

More details can be found on [the dedicated US flyer on the topic](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf). The general rule of thumb seems to be that, if

> Payment, income, salary will be paid to you by U.S. based company or business entity.

then you need a dedicated employment visa. In your case, you will be performing work that is paid by your employer in Canada. So, in principle, you are eligible to enter the US on a B1 visa. If in doubt, contact your local US embassy for precise information.

The additional documents you can bring are those that help explain the reason for your visit.